# Stop Repeating Set Timer Function jQuery

Tags: jquery, time, timer, set

i'm not pro with jquery, but i just made a simple code to show a div, after click another div with 10 sec timer.

This is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.link').click(function() {
    $('#my-timer').fadeIn('slow');
        var settimmer = 0;
        $(function(){
                setInterval(function() {
                    var timeCounter = $("b[id=show-time]").html();
                    var updateTime = eval(timeCounter)- eval(1);
                    $("b[id=show-time]").html(updateTime);

                    if(updateTime == 0){
                    $('#my-timer').hide(); 
                      $('.download').fadeIn('slow'); 
                    }
                }, 1000);           
});
});
        $(".download").hide();
        $("#my-timer").hide();
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="link">Link</div>
<div class="download">Download</div>
<div style="display:none" id="my-timer">Page Will Redirect with in <b id="show-time">10</b> seconds<br />
</div>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/vuJZX/

my problems is:

1: When for first time click on link, everything is ok, but i need to show this timer just for once time! in demo u can see, after every 10 sec, if u click on Link, timer will be start and counting like this, -1, -2, -3, -4 ... how i can stop and disable this timer after 10 sec? i need to disable timer after 10 sec.

2: i need to show this timer for 10 sec, but if u clicking on Link word 3-4 times, timer will be working to fast! i think my problem is timer speed! i dont know how i can explain this problem, but u can try in demo link, just click on Link 4-5 times and look at timer!

and my last question, i don't know my code is standard or not. do i need to change code or is correct?

thanks

Comment: for start counting down from this: <b id="show-time">10</b>

Comment: @Alireza, if you're using `eval` 99% of the time you're doing it wrong. `eval(1)` is the same as `1`. It just doesn't make sense.

Comment: OkiDoki, could u please correct this code for me bro? :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the easiest way to handle it would just be to use `one`.  Since you only want this event to fire once, `one` will unbind the handler after the first click.

```
$('.link').one("click", function() {
```

You will also need to use `clearInterval` to stop the interval once you are done with it.

On a related note, don't use `eval`.  You should be using `parseInt` in this case, or maintain the number in a javascript variable.

http://jsfiddle.net/vuJZX/3

```
$('.link').one("click", function() {
    $('#my-timer').fadeIn('slow');
    var settimmer = 0;
    var counter = 10;
    var interval = -1;
    $(function() {
        interval = setInterval(function() {
            var timeCounter = $("b[id=show-time]").html();
            $("b[id=show-time]").html(counter--);

            if (counter == 0) {
                $('#my-timer').hide();
                $('.download').fadeIn('slow');
                clearInterval(interval);
            }
        }, 1000);
    });
});
```

Comment: +1 Besides using better methods than I did you wrote a much more concise answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the jQuery [`unbind()`](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) function and the native JavaScript [`clearInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.clearInterval) function.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/SO_AMK/rzrez/1/

Comment: Sorry, unbind not settimeout.

Answer (score 1):

i am just edit your fiddle.

```
var timeCounter = 10;
var istimerStart = false;

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.link').click(function() {
    $('#my-timer').fadeIn('slow');

    $(function(){

        if(istimerStart == false){

           setInterval(function() {
              istimerStart = true;
                timeCounter = $("b[id=show-time]").html();
                var updateTime = eval(timeCounter)- eval(1);
                $("b[id=show-time]").html(updateTime);

                if(updateTime == 0){
                   $('#my-timer').hide();
                   $('.download').fadeIn('slow');
                }
            }, 1000);
         }
     });
    });
    $(".download").hide();
    $("#my-timer").hide();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vuJZX/

your mistake : whenever you click on link new interval is start so i set a flag.

Useless Advice: timer function never write in document.ready if it possible do separate function.

(it's not a rule but i followed this to avoid bug).